# Seeking plugin like NetCDF Browser for QGIS 3.0 and above

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, netcdf

Is there a plugin that fulfills the same function as NetCDF Browser (i.e. to browse multi-variable and multi-dimensional NetCDF files) but is available for QGIS versions 3.0 and above?

Comment: Have you seen this issue on the NetCDF Browser https://github.com/etiennesky/netcdfbrowser/issues/5 ? Apparently, QGIS can explore directly NetCDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add your netcdf data as a [Mesh layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_mesh/mesh_properties.html). With [Temporal Controller Panel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgDg5cRwPRw&t=3261s), you can go through the time dimension.